# elasticsearch getting too many results, need help filtering query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having much problem understanding the underlying of ES querying system.

I've got the following query for example:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "referer": "www.xx.yy.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now",
              "lt": "now-1h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "0.5h"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "what": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "host"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That request get too many results:

> "status" : 500,   "reason" :
>   "ElasticsearchException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException:
>   Data too large, data for field [@timestamp] would be larger than limit
>   of [3200306380/2.9gb]]; nested:
>   UncheckedExecutionException[org.elasticsearch.common.breaker.CircuitBreakingException:
>   Data too large, data for field [@timestamp] would be larger than limit
>   of [3200306380/2.9gb]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[Data too
>   large, data for field [@timestamp] would be larger than limit of
>   [3200306380/2.9gb]]; "

I've tryied that request:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "term": {
          "referer": "www.geoportail.gouv.fr"
        }
      },
      {
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": {
            "from": "2014-10-04",
            "to": "2014-10-05"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggs": {
    "interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "0.5h"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "what": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "host"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to filter the data in order to be able to get a correct result, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution, it's kind of weird.
I've followed dimzak adviced and clear the cache:

```
curl --noproxy localhost -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear"
```

Then I used filtering instead of querying as Olly suggested:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query":  {
        "term": {
          "referer": "www.xx.yy.fr"
        }
      },
      "filter" : { 
        "range": {
          "@timestamp": { 
            "from": "2014-10-04T00:00", 
            "to": "2014-10-05T00:00"
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
  "interval": {
    "date_histogram": {
    "field": "@timestamp",
    "interval": "0.5h"
    },
    "aggs": {
    "what": {
      "cardinality": {
      "field": "host"
      }
    }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

I cannot give you both the ansxwer, I think dimzak deserves it best, but thumbs up to you two guys :)

Comment: I came up with another much cleaner solution, I'll let you know when I'm done with testing

Comment: Alexandre Mélard what was your cleaner solution?

Comment: Sorry, I did not have more time for that, I had to let that subject on the side, but I'll try to post something asap

Comment: My problem was similar but just running the clear cache post request solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can try clearing cache first and then execute the above query as shown [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html).

Another solution may be to remove interval or reduce time range in your query...

My best bet would be either clear cache first, or allocate more memory to elasticsearch (more [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html))

Answer (score 4):

Using a filter would improve performance:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query":  {
          "term": {
            "referer": "www.xx.yy.com"
          }
       },
       "filter" : {"range": {
            "@timestamp": { "gte": "now", "lt": "now-1h"
              }
            }
          }
       }
    },
  "aggs": {
    "interval": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "0.5h"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "what": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "host"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may also find that [date range](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html) is better than date histogram - you need to define the buckets yourself.

is the `referer` field being analysed?  or do you want an exact match on this - if so set it to **not_analyzed**.

is there much cardinality in your `hostname` field? have you tried pre-hashing the values?

Comment: when executing your query, I get a SearchPhaseExecutionException

Comment: I've plugged kibana on my ES in order to see if it can do something with my data, but is fails also with the same error:  Data too large, data for field [@timestamp] would be larger than limit of [3200306380/2.9gb]]

Comment: how many results are you expecting you query to return? What level of cardinality do you have in your data?

Comment: I have one timestamp for each record stored in the database (50Go per day)