# Elasticsearch use doc_values at field creation time

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the elastic documentation, you can use doc_values by adding them to your mapping.

```
PUT /music/_mapping/song
{
  "properties" : {
    "tag": {
      "type":       "string",
      "index" :     "not_analyzed",
      "doc_values": true 
    }
  }
}
```

It appears that doc_values can be added automatically when the field is created.

> Setting doc_values to true at field creation time is all that is
>   required to use disk-based fielddata instead of in-memory fielddata.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html

How do you set this value by default?

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926637/elasticsearch-kibana-field-data-too-large)

Answer (score 1):

This will be the standard in 2.0 (enabled by default): https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8312

In the meantime, I can only think of using a dynamic mapping for any *new* fields to have `"doc_values": true`, otherwise (for any static mapping) you need to do this manually for every field where you want `doc_values` enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the info on 2.0. How do I enable this feature for all new fields? Do I edit the elasticsearch.yml file? I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: I mentioned dynamic templates: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates. "New fields" for an index means adding fields that are not already defined in a static mapping for that index.